# Add input value to Alert Dialog Boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

How i can put the value from input type id "email" to my alert box? 
The rest code its working in my opinion,i just cant make the alert box displaying the value from my e-mail form. 
Using bootstrap just too make some cool design.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
<form class="text-center border border-light p-5">

    <p class="h4 mb-4">CHANGE E-MAIL</p>

    <p>Input Old E-mail and New E-mal</p>
    <!-- Name -->
    <input type="email" id="email1" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="E-mail">

    <!-- Email -->
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="E-mail">

    <!-- Sign in button -->
    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" id="tombol_form" type="submit" onclick = "check();">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
</div>
      </div>       
      </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var email=document.getElementById("email").value;

      function check() {
        alert ("Success your email change to: " +email)
       
      
        }
    </script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the input value inside your check function, since otherwise it's got when you website loads, not when you click the button.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
<form class="text-center border border-light p-5">

    <p class="h4 mb-4">CHANGE E-MAIL</p>

    <p>Input Old E-mail and New E-mal</p>
    <!-- Name -->
    <input type="email" id="email1" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="E-mail">

    <!-- Email -->
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="E-mail">

    <!-- Sign in button -->
    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" id="tombol_form" type="submit" onclick = "check();">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
</div>
      </div>       
      </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        

      function check() {
        var email=document.getElementById("email").value; //Moved this into the 'check'-function
        alert ("Success your email change to: " +email)     
      }
    </script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest using the [HTML `<dialogue>` Element] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog). Easy to setup and works like a charm!